# If I rename a sitemap, does it affect my SEO?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitemap, web-crawlers

I would like to rename my sitemap:

1. Would it affect my SEO at all?
2. Would I have to resubmit it on GWT?
3. If I have a `sitemap-index.xml` file, that remains the same, but I change the name of one of the sitemaps within it, will GWT update itself?

`Sitemap-index.xml` contains multiple `sitemap-1.xml`, `sitemap-2.xml` files.

Answer (score 1):

Look's like you're using yoast plugin for WordPress.

1. No, it's not affect at all, I have remove my sitemap many times, and it does not affect at all, Google can re-crawl such a webpages again from their indexed databases.
2. Yes, you should re-submit your new sitemap to GWT.
3. Yoast automatically create post, pages and categories sitemap, and all the sitemap links to main sitemap, because Google don't support large XML sitemap, and hence Yoast automatically part them into short. Don't worry about it, if you change the internal XML file name as well.